# Internal working of importing a module in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to know the internal working of import method . When I searched for the same it displayed only how to use import in perl ,which I do not require.

Comment: It would help us to provide a useful answer if you were to describe why you are asking the question. What will you do with the information?

Answer (score 3):

It's up to each module to provide an `import` method if they want to provide one. Most that do delegate the task to the Exporter module using code like

```
use Exporter qw( import );
```

or the older

```
use Exporter qw( );
our @ISA = 'Exporter';
```

If this is the `import` method about which you are asking, please refer to [the module's documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) for more information.

---

If, on the other hand, you are asking how to dynamically add a subroutine in a namespace, then it's just a question of assigning the sub ref to the glob. This means that

```
sub foo { ... }
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
BEGIN { *foo = sub { ... }; }
```

so you want

```
no strict qw( refs );

*{ $dst_pkg . '::' . $sub_name } = \&{ $src_pkg . '::' . $sub_name };
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I searched for the same it displayed only how to use import in
>   perl, which I do not require. I want to know the internal working of
>   import method.

If you want to know the internals then check the internals i.e. the source.

Below is what `import` subroutine from `Exporter` module does. Go through it, refer documentation and Google if some "keywords" are not known to you. If you do not find any answer then ask here on SO.

```
sub import {
  my $pkg = shift;
  my $callpkg = caller($ExportLevel);

  if ($pkg eq "Exporter" and @_ and $_[0] eq "import") {
    *{$callpkg."::import"} = \&import;
    return;
  }

  # We *need* to treat @{"$pkg\::EXPORT_FAIL"} since Carp uses it :-(
  my $exports = \@{"$pkg\::EXPORT"};
  # But, avoid creating things if they don't exist, which saves a couple of
  # hundred bytes per package processed.
  my $fail = ${$pkg . '::'}{EXPORT_FAIL} && \@{"$pkg\::EXPORT_FAIL"};
  return export $pkg, $callpkg, @_
    if $Verbose or $Debug or $fail && @$fail > 1;
  my $export_cache = ($Cache{$pkg} ||= {});
  my $args = @_ or @_ = @$exports;

  if ($args and not %$export_cache) {
    s/^&//, $export_cache->{$_} = 1
      foreach (@$exports, @{"$pkg\::EXPORT_OK"});
  }
  my $heavy;
  # Try very hard not to use {} and hence have to  enter scope on the foreach
  # We bomb out of the loop with last as soon as heavy is set.
  if ($args or $fail) {
    ($heavy = (/\W/ or $args and not exists $export_cache->{$_}
               or $fail and @$fail and $_ eq $fail->[0])) and last
                 foreach (@_);
  } else {
    ($heavy = /\W/) and last
      foreach (@_);
  }
  return export $pkg, $callpkg, ($args ? @_ : ()) if $heavy;
  local $SIG{__WARN__} = 
        sub {require Carp; &Carp::carp} if not $SIG{__WARN__};
  # shortcut for the common case of no type character
  *{"$callpkg\::$_"} = \&{"$pkg\::$_"} foreach @_;
}
```

Complete source: https://metacpan.org/source/TODDR/Exporter-5.72/lib/Exporter.pm